# Command to remove web.config entry

Tags: iis, web-config, msdeploy, iis-8, appcmd

I am using below command to add an entry in Web.config

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "MarketWorkFlowWebApp" section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /allowDoubleEscaping:false
```

Output :

```
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MarketWorkFlowWebApp" at configuration commit
 path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MarketWorkFlowWebApp"
```

Adding settings is working fine.

To remove the above entry i am using below command

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "MarketWorkFlowWebApp" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering
```

OutPut:

```
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MarketWorkFlowWebApp" at configuration commit
     path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MarketWorkFlowWebApp"
```

But web.config still contains those entries.

So how can remove any existing tags from web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /allowDoubleEscaping:"True"
```

And then to celar it...

```
appcmd.exe clear config "Default Web Site/" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /allowDoubleEscaping
```